# Locked out of admin, I changed default admin URL

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin

I changed the default URL for logging into the back-end of Magento in the configuration settings and now when i browse to it i get a 404.

I was careful to put in the trailing slash as advised and i have tried everything i can find on the net but to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a programming issue?  If not it should not be here.  You can always is the IP address:  `http://<ipaddress>`

Comment: i thought this was the standard spot for magento stuff ? sorry if it's in the wrong place

Comment: it's not programming - it's settings in magento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log in to your database and open the content of the `core_config_data` table.
Set the `admin/url/use_custom` value to 0.
Set the `admin/url/custom` value empty.

Comment: And Empty out your cache, probably in var/cache.

Comment: thanks - i had tried that but it didn't work - since then i found this post [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/15145/).... but i still couldn't get it working - ( for anyone reading this) what i found was that in addition to deleting the cache folder's contents in var i also needed to delete the sessions folder contents  ... it seems this config change is actually buggy or something

Comment: This really is a configuration issue. The system config setting is one of the biggest ongoing pieces of Varien Fail known. Fix in forums here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/274443/ and proper setting for obscuring admin here by editing local.xml http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/284836/

Comment: @Fiasco Labs .... shouldnt it be greyed out though, if it's not working properly ?

Comment: Well, hehe. The System Config AdminURL setting is just a failed programming jitter leftover that should just be removed. It doesn't work, never has, no conditional use exists that would allow successfully using it. Obviously has never had any priority in any bugfix upgrade.

Comment: yea - it's a bad enough issue for a world class system

Comment: My god, this is still broken in 1.6.2.0.  Thanks for wasting two hours of my time Magento! :)  I wrongly assumed that oh, I'd just need to change use_custom to 0, but apparently it's not even close to being that simple.  I'm going to go submit a bug report, maybe that will get someone to remove this nonsense.  How very stupid.